# Убрать цикличность

Tags: php

Вопрос новичковый но сам что то недопетраю. Есть код:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sub1_emailFrom); $i++) {
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (1,2)");
    while ($sub_money2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT users.id, users.money, phones.phone, site.url, rates.taxes FROM users LEFT JOIN phones ON users.id = phones.user_id LEFT JOIN site ON phones.id = site.phones_id LEFT JOIN rates ON site.id = rates.site_id WHERE users.id = {$sub_money2['id']}");
        while ($sub_money3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
            $sub3_result[] = $sub_money3;             
            foreach ($sub3_result as $sub3) {
                if (($sub3['phone'] == $sub1_emailFrom[$i]) || ($sub3['url'] == $sub1_emailFrom[$i])) {
                    $query4 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = ({$sub3['money']} - {$sub3['taxes']}) WHERE users.id = {$sub3['id']}");
                    echo "Обновление у юзера:" . $sub3['id'] . " баланс равен:" . $sub3['money'] . "<br/>";
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Нужно что бы нормально проходил цикл for но почему то циклиться все, подскажите где что поменять что бы цикл работал корректно.
[image: То что получаю по id клиента]

[image: значения с которыми сравниваю]

Comment: Что значит циклиться всё? И что для вас значит корректно? Покажите что показывает цикл сейчас, и что вы хотите получить, так быстрее ответят на ваш вопрос.

Comment: сайчас исполнение кода циклится до включения ограничения времени на скрипт. В конке я получаю вывод строк с надписью ка изменялся баланс пользователя. Тоесть если условие if выполнилось то получаем проверочную надпись на экран. На данный момент количество элементов в `$sub1_emailFrom` 212 элементов а выдает вот что:

Comment: 3 разных цикла это гениально.

Comment: все когда то учились

Comment: `Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499915520  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499917482  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499917482  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499916828  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499916174  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499915520  
    Обновление у юзера:38 баланс равен:999979852  
    Обновление у юзера:38 баланс равен:999979852  
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499917482    
    Обновление у юзера:35 баланс равен:499917482`

Comment: @ASYOU а что вам нужно получить?

Comment: Вот да. Вместо трех бессмысленных циклов лучше написать словами, какую задачу требуется решить.

Comment: Должен получить иземение баланса после каждого выполнения if. То есть берется условие из `$sub1_emailFrom` потом берется значение из БД сравнивается с ним и если подходит баланс изменяется и так дальше пока непереберет все элементы сравнения. for ввел для того что бы каждый раз брался новый баланс а не как без него берется баланс один раз и с одного числа все снимается и по концу записывается только последняя сумма.

Comment: Для полного понимания вашей проблемы, опишите полностью алгоритм, и выгрузку из бд.(не в коментариях а в самом посте)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из столь глубокомысленных объяснений сложно конечно понять, что ему нужно, но я попытаюсь

```
foreach ($sub1_emailFrom as $email)
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = "SELECT users.id, users.money, rates.taxes 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN phones ON users.id = phones.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN site ON phones.id = site.phones_id 
        LEFT JOIN rates ON site.id = rates.site_id 
        WHERE phones.phone = '$email' OR site.url = '$email'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
    $money = $row['money'] - $row['taxes'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = $money WHERE id = $row[id]";
    echo "Обновление у юзера:" . $row['id'] . " баланс равен: $money <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Вроде получилось спасибо большое.